# Find Groups of Rows Conditionally, "with Opposite Value,"

Tags: sql, filter, conditional-statements, grouping

I am seeking a way to `SELECT` rows conditionally without having only compound key A,B (refer to the picture).

Furthermore, I need to select rows where negative value and positive value of column `C` is present; skipping `0`. There may be any combination of row count with `A`, `B` group the minimum is 2 where C has a negative or positive row.

[image]

The data found below is already queried.

Note: I was able to add another column `D`, because we can't use actual values for `C`:

`D = CASE WHEN C < 0 THEN 1 ELSE 2 end`

[image]

So the logic could be `SELECT *` `WHERE SUM(D) >= 3`.

I am fully able to complete this task with another language such as `C#`, but I *have* to get this done using **only** SQL.

I would also like to avoid temporary tables.  Column `D` is not required.

Comment: Yes, Yes, horrible question. I agree the very first sentence admits that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this work?

```
Select tblA.*
FROM tblA
INNER JOIN 
  (select A,B
  from tblA
  Group By A,B
  HAVING
  SUM(case when C<0 then 1 else 2 end) >=3
)X 
on X.A=tblA.A and X.B=tblA.B
```

SQLFiddle
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2078f/2

Comment: Let me test it. The dificulty is I have already 2 joins to even get to this simple sample in the question ;)

Comment: Yes I already see it working, and I mark it as good answer, but the whole underlying case is more complex, so maybe I should ask different question using different sample